# Perl: kill whole tree from any child

Tags: linux, perl

I have a perl script with a few recursively forked instances. What is a good way to kill the whole tree from any forked child? Need not be clean, `kill -9` will suffice.

Comment: `killall`? `kill` with a negative pid?

Comment: Would `kill` with a negative pid eliminate the whole tree from ANY child? I could not find any info supporting that.

Comment: No, it kills a process group.

Comment: That's the thing, I cannot understand if calling `kill 9, -$pid` would kill the process from which `kill` was called and it's children ONLY, or would the ancestor processes get killed as well? Assuming I call `setpgrp 0,0` during forking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the shell starts a process, it makes it the start of a process group.

```
$ perl -MPOSIX -E'
   my $pid = fork();
   say getpgrp(), " ", getpid();
   waitpid($pid, 0) if $pid;
'
6164 6164
6164 6167
```

If none of the children have their process group altered, you could send a signal to the process group. For example, the following will send `SIGTERM` to all process in the same process group as process `1234`:

```
kill -s TERM -1234
```

If some of the children have their process group altered, you will need to throw a catchable signal (e.g. not `SIGKILL`), and the parents of the children with altered process groups will need to explicitly catch and rethrow the signal to those children.